# Error using SPWebConfigModification to update web.config

Tags: powershell, central-administration, web-config, spwebconfigmodification

I am trying to update web.config using SPWebConfigModification and I am getting the following error:

```
Exception calling "ApplyWebConfigModifications" with "0" argument(s): "Object reference not set to an instance of an
object."
At line:11 char:1
+ $app.Parent.ApplyWebConfigModifications();
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullReferenceException
```

This is my powershell script:

```
$app = Get-SPWebApplication http://test:8000/
$mod = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebConfigModification
$mod.Path = “configuration/SharePoint/WebPartLimits”
$mod.Name = “MaxZoneParts”
$mod.Value = “100”
$mod.Sequence = 0
$mod.Owner = “webpartmod”
$mod.Type = 1    
$app.WebConfigModifications.Add($mod)
$app.update()
$app.Parent.ApplyWebConfigModifications();
```

I have verified that $app and $mod are not null. What else could be causing this error?

Answer (score 1):

The error is stating that you can’t call ApplyWebConfigModifications() on $app.Parent.  In this case, it is the Parent property of $app that is null.

SPWebApplication’s Parent property is of type SPPersistedObject which doesn’t have an ApplyWebConfigModifications method and is most likely null in this case as SPWebApplications aren’t hierarchical/nested.

ApplyWebConfigModifications() does exist on the SPWebService property of the SPWebApplication.

The line should read:
$app.WebService.ApplyWebConfigModifications();

Comment: Thanks, this works on all except the central admin, which I also want to update

Comment: What do you mean by “not working on central admin”?  You need to use -IncludeCentralAdministration in the call to Get-SPWebApplication to have it be one of the objects returned.

Comment: Sorry, I mean I get the same error above when $app is set to central admin. All others work

Comment: My guess is CA doesn’t support custom web.config mods.